# 'Default Behavior' for Haskell recursive data types

Tags: haskell, functor, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to write a propositional logic solver in Haskell. I'm representing logical expressions with a recursive data type called 'Sentence' that has several subtypes for different operations - 'AndSentence', 'OrSentence', etc. So I guess it's a tree with several types of node each having 0, 1, or 2 children.

It seems to be working but some of the code is kind of repetitive and I think there ought to be a better way to express it. Basically I have several functions where the 'default behavior' is to just have the function act recursively on the children of a node, bottoming out on certain node types (typically the 'AtomicSentences', which are leaves). So I write a function like:

```
imply_remove :: Sentence Symbol -> Sentence Symbol
imply_remove (ImplySentence s1 s2) = OrSentence (NotSentence (imply_remove s1)) (imply_remove s2)
imply_remove (AndSentence s1 s2) = AndSentence (imply_remove s1) (imply_remove s2)
imply_remove (OrSentence s1 s2) = OrSentence (imply_remove s1) (imply_remove s2)
imply_remove (NotSentence s1) = NotSentence (imply_remove s1)
imply_remove (AtomicSentence s1) = AtomicSentence s1
```

and I want a more concise way to write the lines for 'AndSentence', 'OrSentence', and 'NotSentence'.

It seems like functors are similar to what I want, but that didn't work out... I want to act on the subtrees, not on some values contained in each node of the subtrees.

Is there a right way to do this? Or a more natural way to structure my data?

Comment: I would suggest the [syntactic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syntactic) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a default function that defines how a Symbol should be treated if no transformation applies to it:

```
default_transformation :: (Sentence Symbol -> Sentence Symbol) -> Sentence Symbol -> Sentence Symbol
default_transformation f (ImplySentence s1 s2) = ImplySentence (f s1) (f s2)
default_transformation f (AndSentence s1 s2) = AndSentence (f s1) (f s2)
default_transformation f (OrSentence s1 s2) = OrSentence (f s1) (f s2)
default_transformation f (NotSentence s1) = NotSentence (f s1)
default_transformation f (AtomicSentence s1) = AtomicSentence s1
```

The function takes the specific transformation as a parameter.

If you write your specific transformation you only need to write the cases that a are different from the default and add the default as a last case:

```
imply_remove :: Sentence Symbol -> Sentence Symbol
imply_remove (ImplySentence s1 s2) = OrSentence (NotSentence (imply_remove s1)) (imply_remove s2)
imply_remove s = default_transformation imply_remove s
```

The advantage of this approach is that it maybe easier to implement, because it doesn't need any dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

This looks as a nice case for [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes).

First, we describe your `Sentence sym` type as a type-level fixed point
of a suitable functor.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, LambdaCase #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable  -- from the recursion-schemes package

-- The functor describing the recursive data type
data SentenceF sym r
   = AtomicSentence sym
   | ImplySentence r r
   | AndSentence r r
   | OrSentence r r
   | NotSentence r
   deriving (Functor, Show)

-- The original type recovered via a fixed point
type Sentence sym = Fix (SentenceF sym)
```

The above `Sentence sym` type is almost identical to your original one, except everything must be wrapped inside a `Fix`.
Adapting the original code to use this type is completely mechanical:
where we used `(Constructor ...)`, we now use `Fix (Constructor ...)`. For instance

```
type Symbol = String

-- A simple formula: not (p -> (p || q))
testSentence :: Sentence Symbol
testSentence = 
   Fix $ NotSentence $
      Fix $ ImplySentence
         (Fix $ AtomicSentence "p")
         (Fix $ OrSentence
            (Fix $ AtomicSentence "p")
            (Fix $ AtomicSentence "q"))
```

Here's your original code, with its redundancies (made worse by the extra `Fix`es).

```
-- The original code, adapted
imply_remove :: Sentence Symbol -> Sentence Symbol
imply_remove (Fix (ImplySentence s1 s2)) =
  Fix $ OrSentence (Fix $ NotSentence (imply_remove s1)) (imply_remove s2)
imply_remove (Fix (AndSentence s1 s2)) =
  Fix $ AndSentence (imply_remove s1) (imply_remove s2)
imply_remove (Fix (OrSentence s1 s2)) =
  Fix $ OrSentence (imply_remove s1) (imply_remove s2)
imply_remove (Fix (NotSentence s1)) =
  Fix $ NotSentence (imply_remove s1)
imply_remove (Fix (AtomicSentence s1)) =
  Fix $ AtomicSentence s1
```

Let's perform a test by evaluating `imply_remove testSentence`: the result is what we expect:

```
 -- Output: not ((not p) || (p || q))
 Fix (NotSentence
   (Fix (OrSentence
      (Fix (NotSentence (Fix (AtomicSentence "p"))))
      (Fix (OrSentence
         (Fix (AtomicSentence "p"))
         (Fix (AtomicSentence "q")))))))
```

And now, let's use the nuclear weapons borrowed from recursion-schemes:

```
imply_remove2 :: Sentence Symbol -> Sentence Symbol
imply_remove2 = cata $ \case
   -- Rewrite ImplySentence as follows
   ImplySentence s1 s2 -> Fix $ OrSentence (Fix $ NotSentence s1) s2
   -- Keep everything else as it is (after it had been recursively processed)
   s -> Fix s
```

If we run the test `imply_remove2 testSentence`, we get the same output as the original code.

What does `cata` do? Very roughly, when applied to a function like 
in `cata f`, it builds a *catamorphism*, i.e. a function which

1. takes a formula apart into its subcomponents
2. recursively apply `cata f` to the found subcomponents
3. reassembles the transformed components into a formula
4. passes this last formula (with processed subformulae) to `f` so that the topmost connective can be affected

The last step is the one doing the actual work. The `\case` above performs just the wanted transformation. Everything else is handled by `cata` (and the `Functor` instance which has been automagically generated).

All the above being said, I wouldn't recommend anyone to lightly move to 
`recursion-schemes`. Using `cata` can lead to very elegant code, yet it requires one to understand the involved machinery, which may not be immediate to grasp (it surely wasn't for me).

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called 'generic programming' in Haskell: https://wiki.haskell.org/Generics; an early form was called "Scrap Your Boilerplate", which you also might want to Google.  I haven't tested this, but I think if you use [Uniplate](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/uniplate/)'s `Data.Generics.Uniplate` and `Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data` modules you can define `imply_remove` as

```
imply_remove = transform w where
    w (ImplySentence s1 s2) = OrSentence (NotSentence s1) s2
    w s = s
```

`transform` does the recursion for you.